# how to debug video pause in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have video on website also put small javascript to create button to play/pause video

in separate file or on codepen all working fine so javascript code looks fine

```
let video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/lukasz83/pen/pBbQaR

but on website button not pausing video

https://theseeyes.co.uk/

and have no idea how to debug this problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've defined `myFunction`, but are not invoking it anywhere. You need to add an event listener to your button, and on click, run your function. I hope this helps!

In the CodePen example you posted, they're doing this in the HTML panel:

```
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
```